# Bash expand variable in an another variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following variables

```
my_country_code="green"
x="country"

echo ${my_$x_code}
bash: ${my_$x_code}: bad substitution
```

echo should print green as output, but unable to find any technique which will give the correct output

Comment: `x=country; declare "my_${x}_code=green"; var="my_${x}_code"; echo "${!var}"`

Answer (score 4):

```
my_x_code="my_${x}_code"
echo ${!my_x_code}
```

Comment: Do keep in mind the note re: questions which "...have already been asked and answered many times before" in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of
[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)